# App in Salesforce for Report Distribution Using filters

Tags: email, reporting

I was wondering if you could help me. I was looking for an existing app that allows report distribution in Salesforce.

The idea will be to be able to subscribe to any account to certain reports. The trick is that I'd like to filter those reports using some parameters.

In my case I have a report that returns the number of products that had been sold in the past month. I'd like to have accounts to be subscribed and see the report with **only** their records.

I normally use [URL parameters](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_filter_url.htm&type=5) to filter those, but since the report will need to be distributed through email in an XLSX attachment I don't know how to achieve that.

I tried [Peeklogic Report Sender - FREE](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000FNBYhUAP) but it does not allow me to filter the reports.

Does anybody have any experience on that kind of app?